# Are there wireless file transfer adapter options for the Canon 550D/T2i?

Tags: canon, canon-550d, wireless, file-transfer

Is there an equivalent to the [wireless adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00080OQUM) available for higher-end Canon DSLRs? The closest thing I have found are the [EyeFi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002UT42UI) cards but was wondering if there are any other alternatives.

Comment: I didn't find any sort of wireless adapter for 550D except using that EyeFi, in the official Canon site there's none of it, search in 3rd party accessories also no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are not any for the Rebel line.  The EyeFi is your best option, and works well with the Rebels, especially the T1i, T2i and T3i. The newer EyeFi products support saving to mobile devices running iOS or Android, similar to the Canon wifi adapters pushing to FTP.  It also can push video and RAW to your computer or to their servers.

The biggest disadvantage is that you don't have the wireless tethering feature that the high-end adapters provide.  There are options though, you can look into something like onOne's DSLR Remote, which uses a USB tether to a laptop, and then you use your iPhone or iPad to remotely control and use Live View to frame your shots.  This works really well when framing group shots, and you're out in front of the camera arranging the group, or you're actually in the shot.  It's also helpful for nature photography, when a IR trigger won't reach because of the sun and you don't want to be near the camera.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin. Looks like an EyeFi card is the way to go then for the time being. I'm after the ability to push RAW so it sounds like they'd be ideal. I'll also check out the DSLR remote.

Answer (score 1):

If after two years you're still looking for an answer to this, you can probably make your own with a Raspberrry Pi and gphoto. It's not exactly an off-the-shelf solution, but it's doable.

Comment: I randomly bought a Rasberry Pi not all that long ago :) Will take a look and thanks for replying, even though it's a pretty old thread.

Answer (score 0):

Cam ranger. If you go to tethertools.com they have a product called camranger which is an awesome product that turns your android or iPhone iPad or Mac into a full featured camera controller as well as being able to control multiple cameras simultaneously. The other suggestion being the wifi sdhc card. You don't need to go with eyefi or mobi. Just get any wifi card. Toshiba make one for $40 or less. You can transfer directly to your computer.  Also there is cube. And heaps of other options